# I get this error when I insert a new post in the db "Call to a member function load() on null"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

When I try to add a new post I get the error

**Call to a member function load() on null**

and this is my PostController:

```
public function index($id = NULL)
    $posts = Post::all();

    $user = User::find($id)->load(['posts']);     
    return view('post.index', compact('posts','user'));
}
```

TABLES:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is probability of $id is null or don't exists I can advice at least use  *findOrFail* instead of *find*

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id)->load(['posts']);
```